# *Some* cells not updating with no clear explanation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell which is not updated when I expect it to. It contains the following formula, which uses named ranges:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(@ee_span),
     "",
     SUM(INDEX(ee_span,@ee_index):INDEX(ee_span,@ee_next_support-1)))
```

The formula for `@ee_next_support` is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(@ee_chainage),
     "",
          IF(@ee_short_span=TRUE,
               MATCH(1,(@ee_chainage<ee_chainage)*(ee_NS<>TRUE)*(@ee_index+1<>ee_index),0),
                    MATCH(1,(@ee_chainage<ee_chainage)*(ee_NS<>TRUE),0)))
```

The above formula isn't so important to understand, just know that it *DOES* change automatically based on the drop down `@ee_short_span` which can be TRUE or FALSE. This causes the cell `@ee_next_support` to change from 11, to 10, say. I would expect this to then cause the cell containing the first formulato update, but it doesn't.

I was under the impression that when using `Index` if one of the row or column references is changed then it will automatically update the index. Why isn't this happening?

To be clear:

- Calculations are set to automatic
- The indexes are formatted as numbers
- If I click into the first cell mentioned above and then press 'enter' then it does correctly update, so the formula works, it just isn't updating automatically
- If I reformat the cell without spaces or line breaks the problem persists (it isn't a formatting issue)

Many thanks.

Comment: I have also seen that bug. I believe it's a bug. I usually just quit Excel and open it again and it starts working.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the `INDEX()` construct. Ever since Excel '97 this function is no longer volatile but semi-volatile. This means it no longer re-calculates by itself automatically when changes have been made to the workbook, only recalculates by itself when you open a workbook. See [this](https://www.fm-magazine.com/news/2019/jun/microsoft-excel-volatile-functions-201920646.html) source for example (somewhere in the middle). Not sure if it's a bug really or by design.

Comment: @Andreas the problem is still there after reset.

Comment: Ok. It has worked for me. But my formulas has been very simple `=A1+A2` style and similar.

Comment: I think it may have to do with the named range and excel no longer knowing the connection within the INDEX formula. If you refer to the actual cell/range, would it update as expected? (and for readability you could use LET and name it there).

Comment: @JvdV I was under the impression that Index and Match are not volatile, which is why they are so popular. However, they are meant to change when a relevant cell is updated. That's what is so strange about my problem above.

Comment: I understand, it's what I'd assume at first too though. But since it's clearly not working for you the most logical answer I could think about is that the `INDEX():INDEX()` construct is failing to auto-calculate. But if you are under the impression that `INDEX()` is ***not*** volatile then you are wrong. It's *semi*-volatile.

Comment: @P.b you are right, this is caused by using named ranges. Named ranges aren't a problem when using ```INDEX()``` for a single cell but it is a problem for ```INDEX():INDEX()``` for a range, annoyingly! I don't know why.